# SQL - How to pull records from different tables where the table relates to a primary key

Tags: sql

Ive been stumped on this one problem where I need to query data based on another tables columns.

I have two tables similar to the ones below. I need to pull queries where tableA partno lines up with tableB partno.

**Table A:**

```
partno  class   sale
2342    R   N
2321    R   N
5252    C   Y
89232   C   Y
24123   C   Y
7232    R   Y
```

**Table B:**

```
partno  orderno currency purchprice    mutation
2342    P213    USD   100        12/16/2013
2342    P223    USD   100        12/17/2013
2321    P225    USD   200        12/17/2013
5252    P231    NOK   1000       12/18/2013
89232   P229    NOK   300        12/19/2013
24123   P102    CAD   400        12/20/2013
7232    P233    CAD   5000       12/21/2013
7232    P235    CAD   5000       12/22/2013



 SELECT
       [partno]
      ,[orderno]
      ,[currency]
      ,[purch_price]
      ,[mutation]
  FROM tableB
  WHERE tableA.partno = tableB.partno;
```

However I get this error:

The multi-part identifier ... could not be bound.

Comment: You need to include `TableA` in the `from` clause, preferably using correct `join` syntax.  When you do, you'll discover that `partno` is ambiguous.  Then you should learn the joys of table aliases.

Comment: Please refer this for Table Aliases http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp as mentioned by Gordon in above comment and this for SQL Join http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordons comments is correct  you should include both table names in the FROM clause and qualify the column names

```
 SELECT
       tableB.partno
      ,tableB.orderno
      ,tableB.currency
      ,tableB.purch_price
      ,tableB.mutation
  FROM   tableA, tableB
  WHERE tableA.partno = tableB.partno;
```

You also need to consider unique keys and nulls in the query semantics.  Is part no unique? Is partno not null?